# ¿Como descargar una imagen y guardarlo en el dispositivo?. Con Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic, imagen, archivo

Se como descargar una imagen por medio de un servicio usando responseType Blob y transformarlo en base64
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Servicio

```
/**
 * Servicio
 * @param imageUrl Url de la imagen
 */
getImageUrl(imageUrl: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(imageUrl, {responseType: 'blob'}); // responseType: 'blob'
}
```

Metodo

```
/**
 * Metodo para descargar la imagen
 * @param imageUrl Url de la imagen
 */
downloadImage(imageUrl = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/90807/pexels-photo-90807-large.jpeg') {
    this.service.getImageUrl(imageUrl).subscribe((res: Blob) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const imageBase64 = reader.result;
            console.log(imageUrl, res, imageBase64);
        }, false);
        if (res) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(res);
        }
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Pero en el dispositivo no encuentra el metodo addEventListener de FileReader.

Answer (score 0):

La desventaja de usar el base 64 es el tamaño adicional si se requiere guardar esto en la storage del dispositivo.

Otra Alternativa es guardar el archivo directamente. para ello se requiere el Plugin de ionic [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file)

```
/**
 * Metodo para descargar la imagen y guardarlo directamente en el dispositivo
 * @param imageUrl Url de la imagen
 */
downloadImage(imageUrl = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/90807/pexels-photo-90807-large.jpeg') {
    this.service.getImageUrl(imageUrl).subscribe((data: Blob) => {
        this.file.writeFile(localDir, fileName, data, { replace: true }).then((file: FileEntry) => {
            console.log(file);
        }).catch((e) => {
            // Could not write image
            error(e);
        });
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

NOTA: Si la imagen se encuentra en mismo servidor en dónde estas apuntando tu host puedes usar el mismo servicio anterior sino dara un error de [CORS](https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors)

Una solución a esto es usando el Plugin [HTTP](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http) y cambiando el servicio

```
/**
 * Servicio
 * @param imageUrl Url de la imagen
 */
getImageUrlNative(imageUrl): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(imageUrl, {}, {responseType: 'blob'}); // responseType: 'blob'
}
```

Como vez retorna una promesa hay que cambiar el metodo

```
downloadImage(imageUrl = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/90807/pexels-photo-90807-large.jpeg') {
    this.service.getImageUrlNative(imageUrl).then((res: any) => {
        const data: Blob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
        this.file.writeFile(localDir, fileName, data, { replace: true }).then((file: FileEntry) => {
            console.log(file);
        }).catch((e) => {
            // Could not write image
            error(e);
        });
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Ya con la uri del file puedes crear tu propia cache de imagenes.

[Adicional recurso trabaja bien con ionic 3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader)